# Apache rewrite to add a directory to REQUEST_URI not working on localhost running wamp

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, localhost

I'm running `wamp` on Vista (Apache v2.2.11) and have projects setup such that `http://localhost/projectx` is the base directory for `projectx`.  Now, I want that requests for

```
http://localhost/projectx/somepage/extra
```

will rewrite to

```
http://localhost/projectx/PUBLIC/somepage/extra
```

To that end I have a file in `C:\wamp\www\projectx\.htacces` that is this simple:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PUBLIC
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PUBLIC$1 [L]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work.  The error I'm getting is "The requested URL /PUBLIC was not found on this server".  Thanks.

UPDATE 25-MAR-2010:

As per Michael's solution I removed the absolute path.  For some reason I also needed to add a final slash to the Cond and Rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PUBLIC/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ PUBLIC/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PUBLIC$1 [L]
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ PUBLIC$1 [L]
```

It's probably just the absolute path that is the problem.

You also need to change the `$1` to be zero based so `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ PUBLIC$0 [L]`

Comment: You fix (almost) works.  I'm a little confused though, the first part `^(.*)$` is matching the URI, but the second part with a `/` at the front makes the replacement an absolute path?  How does that relate then to `RewriteBase` when it returns the URI path to its pre-base form?  Also, I get no error for `/localhost/projectx/` and page is forwarded to `/localhost/projectx/PUBLIC/`, but when I try `/localhost/projectx/extra/` I get a 500 internal server error.  Thanks.

Comment: The rewrite base is is the base for your regular expression but the final destination file could be in a separate directory so its path is relative to the .htaccess file's location.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes so much more sense now.  Also, your solution works with one minor addition (see orig. post).

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
RewriteEngine On     
RewriteBase /projectx  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PUBLIC  
RewriteRule  ^(.*)(PUBLIC)(.*)$ /projectx/PUBLIC$3 [L]
```